# Запустить воркеры apache от имени root пользователя

Tags: apache, docker

### Проблема

- создаю docker контейнер на основе apache, и мне нужно что бы все воркеры запускались от имени root

### Что нужно

- запустить воркеры apache от имени root пользователя

### Что пробовал

- заменить директивы User и Group на root `sed -i 's/User daemon/User root/' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`, но после перезагрузки `Apache` отказываеться запускаться с такими привелегиями и рекомендуют пересобрать его с флагом `-DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE`, а это безсмысленно в условиях контейнера (https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/48)

Comment: Зачем он вам рут?

Comment: в контейнере один процесс, и создавать отдельного пользователя под него ненужно, иначе придеться созодавать такого же пользователя во все зависимых контейнерах. В докере рут ограничен контейнером и это безопасно

Comment: почему бессмысленно-то?

Comment: @Etki выше ответил на подобный вопрос

Comment: @duhon нет, почему бессмысленно собрать апач с нужными флагами?

Comment: @Etki потому что я беру официальнный слой Apache где он уже собран так как они задумали. Если я хочу пересобрать то я уже не могу воспользоваться официальным Apache. Мне проще будет создать полностью свой, но тогда мне трудно будет следить за обновлением. Возможно нужно создать issue создателям слоя что бы они добавили возможность использовать рут

Comment: @duhon вопрос с обновлениями открытый (правда, на них действительно нужно реагировать только в случае какого-нибудь heartbleed), но я не раз и не два делал изображения того, что уже есть, под себя.

Answer (score 2):

Пересоберите Apache с указанным флагом. Другого способа нет - там стоит явная проверка, которая не позволяет воркерам запускаться от рута ни при каких условиях.